# How to tell macro to execute code on specific row?

Tags: vba, excel

Previously I have created an Excel sheet which obtains data from a master table and perform Index & Match formula on selected columns based on what was keyed in the first column.

The code I came up with was:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a4:a9999")) Is Nothing Then

 With Me.Range("b4:b9999")
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(A4,table[Project No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(A4,table[Project No],FALSE),2))"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

 With Me.Range("c4:c9999")
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(A4,table[Project No],FALSE),3)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(A4,table[Project No],FALSE),3))"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
End If

End Sub
```

How it works is when the first column detects any changes within the range a4 to a9999, it will change all the values in column b and c based on the range as well.

Currently I'm trying to modify it so that data will only change based on which row I select. For example, if I change the data in A5 only, I want B5 and C5 only to perform the code and the others remain unchanged.

Is it possible to use worksheet_change to perform this or do I need another approach entirely?

As an extension to the question, what happens if I want the same function to work in a table? The code used for table version is such:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

If Not Intersect(target, Me.ListObjects("ProjectEntry").ListColumns("Asset No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

 With Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]")
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),2))"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

 With Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Preventive Stroke]")
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),3)),"""",INDEX(DieMaster,MATCH(B4,DieMaster[Asset No],FALSE),3))"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

End If

End Sub
```

How would I code in the function if range is a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only changing one cell at a time, the change is reasonably simple - use `Target` to specify what to change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a4:a9999")) Is Nothing Then

 With Target.Offset(0, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),2))"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

 With Target.Offset(0, 2)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),3)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),3))"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
End If

End Sub
```

I changed the code to use R1C1 notation when specifying the formulas, as I find that easier to read in this sort of situation.  For example, in A1 notation you would need to use a formula in column B of

```
    .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(A" & Target.Row & ",table[Project No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(A" & Target.Row & ",table[Project No],FALSE),2))"
```

---

If you wish to clear cells in columns B & C when the cell in column A is cleared, just add an `If` statement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a4:a9999")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
            'Clear column B and C if column A is empty
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Clear
        Else

            With Target.Offset(0, 1)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),2)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),2))"
                .Value = .Value
            End With

            With Target.Offset(0, 2)
                .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),3)),"""",INDEX(MasterEntry,MATCH(RC1,table[Project No],FALSE),3))"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the code you gave me and it works. However I seem to lost a function from my old code, that is when I delete the content from cell A the content in cell B and C will also delete as well. Now when I delete the content of a cell in column A, the others remain. Granted its not that big of a deal (I can always manually delete it) but is there a way to tell it to do it automatically?

Comment: I tried it and doesn't seem to be working... I did do some modifications to the code. In particularly `If Not Intersect(target, Range("a4", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))) Is Nothing Then` where I change it so it refers to everything instead of needing to change range every time limit reached. Also I switched the formula to IFERROR. It can still fill in no problem but cannot remove as your code suggested. Is it possible that these changes are affecting the code?

Comment: Also I should mention that column A uses drop down menu to select data. And I simply click the cell I want to delete and click Backspace.

Comment: @hjh93 Changing it to only execute the code if it is within the "used" part of column A should work, **providing you don't try to clear the last row in column A** (because, by the time the code gets to run, that cell is no longer in the "used" area). You can get around that by just using `If Target.Row > 3 And Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the second part of the question, the following code shows how to only update the edited row for a table.

Note that I've changed from inserting formulae into the sheet, to doing the calculations in VBA and inserting the values into the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Asset No]")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Dim Ä As Excel.Application: Set Ä = Excel.Application
  Dim varMatchRowNum As Variant
  Dim varValue As Variant

  varMatchRowNum = Ä.Match(Target.Value2, Ä.Range("DieMaster[Asset No]"), 0)
  With Ä.Range("DieMaster").ListObject.ListColumns
    varValue = Ä.Index(.Item(2).DataBodyRange, varMatchRowNum)
    Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Description]").EntireColumn.Cells(Target.Row).Value _
    = IIf(IsError(varValue), vbNullString, varValue)

    varValue = Ä.Index(.Item(3).DataBodyRange, varMatchRowNum)
    Me.Range("ProjectEntry[Preventive Stroke]").EntireColumn.Cells(Target.Row).Value _
    = IIf(IsError(varValue), vbNullString, varValue)
  End With

End Sub
```

Note the usage of `Application.` instead of `WorksheetFunction.` to access the worksheet functions. This, coupled with the use of Variant type variables, allows us to trap the error that occurs if the match fails.